# How are the columns and rows counted in pascal function in Functional Programming Principles in Scala at coursera?

Tags: scala

I'm learning Scala while going through the Coursera course [Functional Programming Principles in Scala](https://www.coursera.org/course/progfun).

The first exercise says:

> ```
>     1
>    1 1
>   1 2 1
>  1 3 3 1
> 1 4 6 4 1
> ```
>
> The numbers at the edge of the triangle are all 1, and each number
>   inside the triangle is the sum of the two numbers above it. Write a
>   function that computes the elements of Pascal’s triangle by means of a
>   recursive process.
>
> Do this exercise by implementing the pascal function in Main.scala,
>   which takes a column c and a row r, counting from 0 and returns the
>   number at that spot in the triangle. For example, pascal(0,2)=1,
>   pascal(1,2)=2 and pascal(1,3)=3.

At the start, I understand, as he refers to the 'numbers' we are all familiar with, but then he goes on to use the term "elements." What does he mean by this? What does he want me to compute?

I assumed that he got bored with the word "number" and thought, after defining the names of the numbers in the triangle as 'numbers' he just wanted to use something new, thus "element," but no matter how I count I cannot get the references to work.

I cannot even really understand the term 'column' seeing as the numbers are not vertically above each other.

Can you please explain how he gets `pascal(1,3) == 3`?

Comment: sorry, but users have to log-in to see the exercise - could you post the exercise please? Or maybe something similar - I don't know about the copyright actually.

Answer (score 3):

You're thinking about columns a bit wrong. By "xth column," he means the "xth entry in a given row.

So, if you are looking at the function `pascal(c,r)`, you would want to figure out what the cth number is in the rth row.

So, for example:

`pascal(1,2)` corresponds to the second entry in the 3rd row

```
      1
    1   1
  1  *2*  1
```

`pascal(1,3)` wants you to look at the second entry in the 4th row.

```
       1
     1   1
   1   2   1
 1  *3*  3   1
```

Comment: thanks that makes it clear - the rows are horizontal, i was ok with them but the columns are not vertical that threw me

Answer (score 2):

Just count from the left. (0,2) is the leftmost number in the row

> **1** 2 1

so (1,3) would be the second number in

> 1 **3** 3 1

Answer (score 2):

You can simply make the triangle "rectangle", and everything will become apparent:

```
cols-> 0 1 2 3 4

row-0  1
row-1  1 1
row-2  1 2 1
row-3  1 3 3 1
row-4  1 4 6 4 1
```

And you were right in that the triangle's "elements" are made of numbers, though there's a subtle difference, but insubstantial in this case.

*P.S.* I would personally advice to prefer the course forum for such questions:

1. It will avoid controversial issues on the honor code.
2. Your course fellows will have a quicker understanding of the problem at hand
3. They will have access to material which is not available to those not undertaking the course
4. It will help to build up a sense of membership amongst the course students, and give you all a chance to create new, possibly fruitful, relashionships

Comment: course ended months ago - but thanks for your nice explanation

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I thought there was a new one already started... in fact I believe it'll be in March.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking is against the Coursera Honor Code: https://www.coursera.org/maestro/auth/normal/tos.php#honorcode
http://www.aiqus.com/questions/41299/coursera-cheating-scala-course

Comment: I don't think that's the case. He's trying to understand the problem, not trying to get someone to give him the solution.

Comment: Actually I think asking for clarification of the actual problem is OK. But the discussion forum of the course might be a better place to ask.

Comment: i was trying to understand the question - i will write the solution myself. I do think it was poorly worded.

Answer (score 0):

I loved solving this exercise.
My thought process was the following:

- Understanding that the problem is a literal description of the binomial coefficient. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient
- Understanding that the ask is a literal plug into the fomula `(!row) / ((!col) * !((row - c)))` and the formula is right there in the wiki page
- Now the only thing that is missing now is implementing a tail recursive function of factorial
- Bonus. if you use the extension method as such

```
extension (int: Int) {
 def ! = factorialTailRec(int)
}
// you get to write
(r.!) / ((c.!) * ((r - c).!))
```

You get to write almost the identical mathematical formula. And at that moment I realised the similarities between doing maths and programming. And I cried a little with the beauty of it.